# Generating a plain GUID in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, guid

[image: Create GUID box]

If I try using the "Create GUID" tool using "Tool" > "Create GUID", I get a box that has six different snippets which contains GUIDs. But it doesn't offer the option of providing only the GUID. Is there any way to do this?

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019, version 16.1.6, and .NET version 4.8.03761.

Comment: You can find alternative ways from posts like https://kristian.hellang.com/generating-guids/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command (language C#) for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to insert a plain GUID:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        ts.Text = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35):

Instead of installing a new extension (as mentioned in the other answers), you can just use a built-in tool in Visual Studio called "C# Interactive".

Here are the steps:

1. On VS open the "C# Interactive" window (if not opened) by
   pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and typing "C# Interactive"
2. Type the following in the window and press enter:
   `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

And you'll get the result:

[image]

---

P.S. Basically we just execute a C# code in the "C# Interactive" window.
You can modify the code there to whatever you want.
For example, you can go further and generate a list of guids with by typing there a code like this:

```
> for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The Create UID option is available by default in Professional and Enterprise versions. To have Create GUID functionality you can add the Create GUID tool yourself by following the below steps.

1. Go to the Visual Studio menu and click on *Tools* then *External Tools*.

   [image: Visual Studio Tools]
2. The below model will pop up.

   [image: New Tool Popup Modal]

   ```
   Title: Create GUID
   Command: Powershell.exe
   Arguments: [guid]::NewGuid()
   Use Output Window: Check/True
   ```
3. Click Apply then OK.
4. Now again go to VS Menu -> *Tools* and you'll be able to see the *Create GUID* option in the Tools menu.

   [image: Create GUID Option]
5. Click on *Create GUID* and check the output window.

   [image: Generated GUID]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30324549)

Comment: Dear these links are Images I Uploaded not allowed to post images as I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Can this generate multiple Guids in one action? Like it promts for how many Guids you want, and then it will print them via powershell? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools > External Tools

[image]

Title: `Create &GUID`

**Visual Studio 2022**

Command: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe`

Initial Directory: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools`

**Visual Studio 2019**

Command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe`

Initial Directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools`

It is possible that your directories may be different.  Just search for "guidgen.exe" if you have issues finding it.

Now you can go Tools > Create Guid and see:

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you use the & sign in the title? I think the title value is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Install this extension: [Insert Guid by Mads Kristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.insertguid) (works with
Visual Studio 2017, 2019, 2022).

And you will have a new entry in the **Edit** menu (with the shortcut
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>):

[image]

That will insert a GUID exactly in the point you are in the code.

Comment: As long as you have this extension installed: [Insert Guid by Mads Kristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.insertguid)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my version of the External Tool solution.
This version is based on @MMUNEEBALI solution but extends it by copying the GUID to the clipboard.

- Title: NEW GUID (Clipboard)
- Command: Powershell.exe
- Arguments: $guid = (New-Guid).Guid; Set-Clipboard $guid; Write-Host New GUID [$guid] copied!
- Use Output Window: Check/True
- Close on exit: Check/True

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).